# Evaluation metrics on Spark ML multiclass classification problem

Tags: apache-spark-ml

I am looking for a Multiclass classification example using Spark-Scala but I am unable to find one yet. Specifically speaking, I want to train a classification model and see all the associated metrics on training and test data.

Does Spark ML (DataFrame based API) support confusion matrix on multi-class problems?

I am looking for Spark v 2.2 and above examples. An end-to-end example would be really useful. I can't find confusion matrix evaluation here -

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/ml-classification-regression.html

Answer (score 1):

this should be it:

```
val metrics = new MulticlassMetrics(predictionAndLabels)
println(metrics.confusionMatrix)
```

classification metrics are here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html

Comment: thanks for the link. But are these metrics available in the Dataframe based API too ?- I mean the `ml` API .

Comment: looks like they are not, but you can easily convert DF to rdd: `val rows: RDD[Row] = df.rdd`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `model` is your trained model, and `test` is the test-set,
this is the code snippet for calculating the confusion-matrix in `python`:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import MulticlassMetrics
predictionAndLabels = model.transform(test).select('label', 'prediction')
metrics = MulticlassMetrics(predictionAndLabels.rdd.map(lambda x: tuple(map(float, x))))

confusion_matrix = metrics.confusionMatrix().toArray()
labels = [int(l) for l in metrics.call('labels')]
confusion_matrix = pd.DataFrame(confusion_matrix , index=labels, columns=labels)
```

Note that the `metrics.labels` is not implemented in `pyspark` for some reason, so we're calling the `scala` backend directly